# set background color at text overflow visible using css

Tags: html, css

I set my `<P>` tag with fix height and `overflow:hidden`. and on hover effect of it, I set `overflow:visible;`

my problem is text is display but I want to set `z-index` and background color of `<p>`,background display only for `max-width` of `<P>`. i want change background color at height of text it covered.

CSS:

```
.oe_description {   
   overflow:hidden;
   max-height:4.2em;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.oe_description:hover {
   overflow:visible;
   position:relative;
   z-index:100;
   background: #e5f2f7; 
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

see: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7091qus/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c7091qus/1/)

You could use `max-height: none;` to `.oe_description:hover`

**CSS:**

```
.oe_description {   
   overflow:hidden;
   /* 4 times the line-height to show 4 lines */
   /*max-height: 5.6em;*/
   /* 3 times the line-height to show 3 lines */
   max-height:4.2em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.oe_description:hover {
   overflow:visible;
   position:relative;
   z-index:100;
   background: #e5f2f7; 
   font-weight:bold;
   max-height: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-xs-10 non_padding">
    <p class="oe_description">
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
       When text must stay on one line, but there is not enough room for it all, this article provides a solution.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for answer,thanks it work, but it change parent div height,is there any other solution?

Comment: But it's the same height as your `<p>` tag's text height, Right? and you could use `margin: 0px` to your `<p>` tag...

Comment: ya but `<p>` effect my parent div, its done to change position:relative to absolute.

Comment: problem is when i merge this with my code,it change outer div height, i want fix height, see this http://jsfiddle.net/c7091qus/4/

Comment: @i'mPosSible but it's the same even if you don't use hover - http://jsfiddle.net/c7091qus/6/ or http://jsfiddle.net/c7091qus/6/show

Comment: @i'mPosSible yea, but you could set `max-width: 645px`... or use CSS `@media queries` and align the text to middle

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with having a scroll bar, you could change the overflow option to :auto. Solves the content display issue, sticks to the same div height and transforms the background color accordingly.

```
.oe_description:hover {
   overflow:auto;/*for scroll*/
   position:relative;
   z-index:100;
   background: #e5f2f7; 
   font-weight:bold;     
}
```